# File Copy vs Another Choice?

Tags: c#

I want to copy a file to a directory. I thought it would be a simple enough process.

This is the code im using:

```
string strSrcPath = "C:\Users\Documents\Development\source\11.0.25.10\",
strDstPath = "C:\Users\Documents\Development\testing\11.0.25.10\",
strFile = "BuildLog.txt"

File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourcePath, sourceFile), strDstPath);
```

The problem here is that when i'm doing the File.Copy it wants to copy one file to another, but I dont want to do that since the file does not exist in the destination path. Therefore I get thrown an error which states something along the lines of 'Cannot copy, strDstPath is a destination not a file"

Was there something I could use instead of File.Copy to copy a file that doesnt exist in the destinaion from the source to destination?

Comment: Escape the \ with @"c:\users\..." or "c:\\users\\..."

Comment: Did you retype this or is this your actual code? There are a large number of syntax errors, so I'm guessing it's the former. It's hard to help you if you aren't showing us your actual code.

Comment: @MikePrecup It's retyped. There's a lot of code involved in it so I figured this would be the easier way.

Comment: @user2619395: There is a small free program called linqpad that allows you to run small snippets of code without having to compile them up manually and so on. Its basically like a text editor with a compiler. Its great for writing SO questions because you can test your code actually works (as well as the nature of the question allows - ie variables correct, etc.) before putting it in a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the parameters are the source filename and the destination filename. You are passing a destination directory and the program is confused because you can't make the file into a directory.

Use instead:

```
File.Copy(Path.Combine(strSrcPath , strFile ), Path.Combine(strDstPath, strFile);
```

Comment: Yup that makes more sence now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be passing some wrong parameter to the `Path.Combine` (the second one). It should be `strFile` instead of `sourceFile` which is quite unclear where is it coming from.

And you also need to provide a filename for the destination folder:

```
File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourcePath, strFile), Path.Combine(strDstPath, strFile));
```

You also need to escape the `\` characters in your string because your code will probably not compile. This could be done by either using `\\` or by using the `@` character at the beginning of your string.

```
string strSrcPath = @"C:\Users\Documents\Development\source\11.0.25.10\",
strDstPath = @"C:\Users\Documents\Development\testing\11.0.25.10\",
strFile = "BuildLog.txt"

File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourcePath, strFile), Path.Combine(strDstPath, strFile));
```

Also make sure that the destination folder you specified exists. If it doesn't exist you need to create it first (using the [`Directory.CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx) method).

Comment: sourcePath doesn't exist either.. I think that line is disconnected from his actual code altogheter

Comment: Yeah sorry, it was poorly retyped psudo-esque code. Thank you though!

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify a filename for your destination

so

```
File.Copy("XMLFile1.xml", @"c:\temp");
```

will fail where

```
File.Copy("XMLFile1.xml", @"c:\temp\XMLFile1.xml");
```

will not